# Vimeo fullscreen not working on jquery colorbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, youtube, colorbox, vimeo

I am using jquery colorbox to load images/ videos. But I have this vimeo fullscreen problem with it.

The fullscreen works fine on colorbox as I only have to provide the link like this,

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/sBWPCvdv8Bk?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent
```

As for vimeo, I have to provide the link like this,

```
http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=24214057
```

So both types works fine with the colorbox iframe, the only problem is that the vimeo fullscreen is not working at all but youtube ones are fine.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try embedding the Vimeo video like this?

```
http://player.vimeo.com/video/24214057
```

Comment: thank you. got it working with this finally - `http://player.vimeo.com/video/24456787?autoplay=1` :-)

Comment: I get a :XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://player.vimeo.com/video/24456787?autoplay=1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
with this